# YouTube Data API LiveChatId assistance

Tags: c#-4.0, youtube, youtube-api, live-streaming, google-apis-explorer

I've looked online for quite some time now, and I have come up empty. I am working in C#, and I am trying to locate the code I can use to get the liveChatId so I can post to livestream chat. Even the "Try it now" section of Google's example resource https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list#try-it asks for the liveChatId as well. I know I need to make a HTTP GET request, but I really need the actual code that will allow me to do this.

Assistance is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here, from the very [documentation you provided](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list#try-it):

> The `liveChatId` parameter specifies the ID of the chat whose messages will be returned. The live chat ID associated with a broadcast is returned in the `liveBroadcast` resource's `snippet.liveChatId` property.

That means you first need to get your [`liveBroadcast` resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#resource). You can obtain those at the [`liveBroadcasts.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) endpoint. If you want to retrieve broadcasts that you (or a user of your application) is the owner of, you might consider [authenticating with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens) and using the [`mine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#mine) parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I had already gotten the code I needed to perform an OAuth2.0 request and authenticate. I was looking for the code that would allow me to query Google's servers and be returned with the liveChatId. Since this point, I have found out the actual code I need.

Thanks for the effort though!